# How to add new object in an array without affecting the other objects iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I would like to know how to do when you click a button it will add a new object in the array and it will not affect the other objects like this:

here is my code:

```
x = x + 1;
dictData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

    [dictData setObject:[menuData itemName] forKey:@"dishName"];
    [dictData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"quantity"];
    [dictData setObject:[menuData itemPrice] forKey:@"price"];

    [arrMut addObject:dictData];
}
```

This is the current output

```
{

 name = charles1;

},{

name = charles1;

}
```

This is the expected output

```
{

  name = charles1;

},{

name = charles2;

}
```

Comment: You can use the addObjects property of array.

Comment: Please show your code where you are creating your objects and adding them to the array. The code is necessary to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1):

because you are adding a same dictionary

change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    dictData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // move this line to inside of the loop
    [dictData setObject:[menuData itemName] forKey:@"dishName"];
    [dictData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"quantity"];
    [dictData setObject:[menuData itemPrice] forKey:@"price"];

    [arrMut addObject:dictData];
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    [arrMut addObject:[@{@"dishName" : [menuData itemName],
                         @"quantity" : @"1",
                         @"price" : [menuData itemPrice],
                        } mutableCopy]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Bryan Chen! Thank you for your response. I tried your answer but it the output is this:


( {

        dishName = "Singapore Shrimp Rolls";

        price = "263.39";
        quantity = 1;
    },
        {
        dishName = "Singapore Shrimp Rolls";
        price = "263.39";
        quantity = 1;
    })

It has the same value. thats my problem I have different data in the array

Comment: `i` was never used to create dictionary, so everything always created with same value, is this what you expected?

Comment: I need to have this output

( { dishName = "Singapore Shrimp Rolls"; price = "263.39"; quantity = 1; }, { dishName = "Sushi Rolls"; price = "123.39"; quantity = 2; })

Thank you.

Comment: then you need to read different value in each iteration. and replace `@"1"` with something like `@(i)` or `[@(i) description]` if it need to be string

Answer (score 0):

The [menuData itemName] method seems to be returning the same object everytime.
You could insert menuData objects in an array and then access a menuData object on each iteration of the for loop.

```
 NSMutableArray *arrMenuData = //This array should contain the menuData objects
 for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
dictData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // move this line to inside of the loop
[dictData setObject:[[arrMenuData objectAtIndex:i] itemName] forKey:@"dishName"]; //A typecast to menuData type may be required, please test.
[dictData setObject:@"1" forKey:@"quantity"];
[dictData setObject:[[arrMenuData objectAtIndex:i] itemPrice] forKey:@"price"];

[arrMut addObject:dictData];
```

}